# Clean up dead references with Mongoose populate()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

If a user has an array called "tags":

```
var User = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    tags: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Tag',
        required: true
    }],
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

and I do a populate('tags') on a query:

```
User.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate("tags")
    .exec(function(err, user) { ... });
```

If one of the tags in the list has actually been deleted, is there a way to remove this dead reference in "tags"?

Currently, the returned user object *IS* returning the desired result -- ie. only tags that actually exist are in the tags array... however, if I look at the underlying document in mongodb, it still contains the dead tag id in the array.

Ideally, I would like to clean these references up lazily.  Does anyone know of a good strategy to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried to find some built-in way to do that but seems that mongoose doesn't provide such functionality.

So I did something like this

```
User.findById(userId)
    .populate('tags')
    .exec((err, user) => {
        user.tags = user.tags.filter(tag => tag != null);

        res.send(user); // Return result as soon as you can
        user.save(); // Save user without dead refs to database
    })
```

This way every time you fetch user you also delete dead refs from the document. Also, you can create `isUpdated` boolean variable to not call `user.save` if there was no deleted refs.

```
const lengthBeforeFilter = user.tags.length;
let isUpdated = user.tags.length;

user.tags = user.tags.filter(tag => tag != null);
isUpdated = lengthBeforeFilter > user.tags.length;

res.send(user);

if (isUpdated) {
    user.save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you delete these tags via mongoose, you can use the post middleware.

This will be executed after you've deleted a tag.

```
tagSchema.post('remove', function(doc) {
     //find all users with referenced tag
     //remove doc._id from array
});
```

Comment: It seems strange, but I was hoping to find a way to do it that doesn't require removing the tag from each user at the time of deletion.... rather, I'd like to do it on populate the next time the user is fetched.

Comment: I have a database with millions of tagged users...  On it, I would like to have *temporary* dead references that get cleaned up over time instead of hitting  hard whenever a tag is deleted from the system.

Answer (score -1):

its sample **retainNullValues: true**

Example:

```
 User.findById(req.params.id)
 .populate({
      path: "tag",
      options: {
        retainNullValues: true
      }
    })
```